# Does the "O" in this google doodle for Olga Ladyzhenskaya have anything to do with her work, or is it completely fanciful?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, history, differential-equations, navier-stokes

[Google Doodle celebrates mathematician Olga Ladyzhenskaya](https://www.cnet.com/news/google-doodle-celebrates-mathematician-olga-ladyzhenskaya/)

She was famous for fluid dynamics and partial differential equations, both of which are beyond my pay grade. And she worked on the Navier-Stokes equation(s?). Does this circle with the arrows represent anything in particular?

All I know from differential equations is they sometimes involved arrows in "direction fields" which may be a connection.

Comment: You might wish to move the question to the suitable [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The equation is a Navier-Stokes equation for viscous flow and the doodle is probably dealing with turbulent flow causing vortexes.

Comment: I've added the question to the History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange. Thx.

Comment: Answered on HSM SE. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/does-the-o-in-the-google-doodle-for-olga-ladyzhenskaya-have-anything-to-do-wit